# All checkboxes are get selected in List instead of only clicked one in codename one

Tags: list, checkbox, codenameone

I have created my own Renderer class and I am doing something like

```
MyClass extends Container implements ListCellRenderer
```

I added some TextAreas Labels with CheckBox into this class..
and setting this as a renderer to "List"

So my code for initListModel is:

```
@Override
protected boolean initListModelReceiptLineList(List cmp) {
    cmp.setRenderer(new RendererPOReceiptList(receiptLineList));
    //valid data in receiptLineList
    cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(receiptLineList));
    return true;
}
```

Everything is running fine, even data are also set in label & textareas..
running good in device and in emulator..

But,
The issue is, when I select 1st checkbox, all checkboxes are selected..

Anyone have any idea please,

Thanks,

Akash

Answer (score 0):

The renderer is stateless hence you shouldn't check the checkbox, you [check the model](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/12/deeper-in-the-renderer.html). Your renderer needs to select the value of the checkbox with every renderer.

This all might be complex stuff which is why I wouldn't recommend building your own and instead using a MultiList (or just adding checkboxes to a container).

Comment: actually my issue is,  
when some value is there then only display field(container) else remove whole container  
[See image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulqrpautqkkw00s/codename1.png?dl=0)   
So it is more difficult if I dont use my own renderer.  
or please suggest some other best which let me do above thing, i.e. remove some container(parent) when its containing(child) textarea is not having some value.   
</br></br>that is why I use my own renderer to remove that container, but then issue with it is that checkbox..  
</br></br>What would be best solution?
Thanks,Akash

Comment: Renderers have the same size in the list http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/12/deeper-in-the-renderer.html

Comment: Yes I gone through that and I already implemented that.  
but just want to know is it possible to remove some container (from list item) based on condition like 
`if(!someValue.length()>0){
((Container)containerDetail.getComponentAt(5)).removeAll();
}`
  
and how can I get that functionality by CodenameOne.
Apology for my English  
Thanks,

Comment: That won't work since the renderer wasn't designed for that. Rubber stamp means that it is replicated again and again for performance and if you change it (other than content) you break everything. Don't use a List, you don't need a list. Just use a BoxLayout Y container.